# Maple graphing inaccuracy

Tags: plot, maple

I am not used to using Maple, so this question may be fairly basic.
However, I cannot find anything helpful on the internet.

I am currently using Maple 13.
I need to draw the graph or find the solution of the following function:

```
    f(x)=arccos(cos((1/273)*(2*Pi*10)*t)*cos(2*Pi*t*(1/365))+cos(6*Pi*(1/180))*sin((1/273)*(2*Pi*t*10))*sin(2*Pi*t*(1/365)))
```

And using the "plot" method in Maple, I tried to draw the graph, and as you can see, the function is periodic, so I expected the graph to be so. However, the graph was not periodic at all.

Also, using the "fsolve" method, I tried to find the root of the equations, only to find out the disappointing result: "0.", the most trivial solution of all.

I figured out that the reason for the error might be in the function itself, or maybe it's just the floating point representation, since no computer code can handle an irrational number exactly.

Is there any way to handle the numbers and/or the sin, cos, arccos functions more accurate to make the outcome get better?

Comment: Hint: The first positive root of your function is 273*365 = 99645, and that's also the period. What makes you think that the plot is inaccurate? It looks fine to me in Maple 18.

Comment: I thought so at the start, but when I zoomed out to see the period, the graph started to go awry, and the graph is definitely not periodic. I'm pretty sure of it, and several of my friends has confirmed it. Maybe Maple 13 has a bug...?

Comment: The graph goes up and down hundreds of times in each period. There's no way that you're going to be able to "see" the period on a plot! Think about what this exercise is trying to teach you. Like I said, the period is exactly 99645. There's no bug.